# Android Studio doesn't start on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: android-studio, crash

I have Ubuntu 16 64bit with Mate.
Android studio worked normally since today.
Now, when i write `./studio` in terminal, i have:

```
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 5.3.1 20160413

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.<clinit>(LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.java:54)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentList(ContainerUtil.java:2550)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createLockFreeCopyOnWriteList(ContainerUtil.java:2425)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryValue.<init>(RegistryValue.java:36)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.get(Registry.java:48)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.is(Registry.java:55)
   at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.blockATKWrapper(UIUtil.java:108)
   at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:95)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.16)
   ...2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find 'theUnsafe' field in the class sun.misc.Unsafe
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.getUnsafe(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:44)
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.<clinit>(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:38)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   ...14 more
```

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"

```
Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.<clinit>(LockFreeCopyOnWriteArrayList.java:54)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentList(ContainerUtil.java:2550)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createLockFreeCopyOnWriteList(ContainerUtil.java:2425)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryValue.<init>(RegistryValue.java:36)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.get(Registry.java:48)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.Registry.is(Registry.java:55)
   at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.blockATKWrapper(UIUtil.java:108)
   at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:95)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:339)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:312)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:291)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find 'theUnsafe' field in the class sun.misc.Unsafe
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.getUnsafe(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:44)
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.<clinit>(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:38)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.16)
   ...14 more
```

Why is this happening? How can i fix this error?

Comment: Seem like you occasionally installed java 1.5 (may be as part of other software), check what java sdk you have and update it to 1.8 (or update env param JAVA_HOME). I suppose it will fix the problem.

Comment: You were right: thank you!

Comment: @sphinks write an answer and I will mark it as the right answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you occasionally installed java 1.5 (may be as part of other software), check what java sdk you have and update it to 1.8 (or update env param JAVA_HOME). I suppose it will fix the problem.